# WEBI: Trying to get a value based off of 2 other values being true

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a formula that shows when an account has purchased an item :

```
placement=Sum(If(([Sale Qty]+0>0 And ([Sale Items Qty]+0>=1));1)ForEach([Customer Nbr]))
```

The issue I am having is that I need to show when a customer has purchased both possible items.

So far this is the formula that has come closest to working :

```
=Sum(If([placement]>1 ForEach([Customer Nbr]);1))
```

What I am looking for is to have the result only show a 1 when both items are purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to do this with a formula I am going to take an approach of one query per item and then merge the results. I will use the e-Fashion universe with City corresponding to your Customer and Category to your Item.

Here are my queries...

[image]

[image]

And the results from those queries...

[image]

Next I will merge the City dimensions.

Now I can create a variable for Category from Query 1 (Category = Mini city)...

[image]

Do the same for Category from Query 2 (Category = T-Shirts).

Now we can put the merged City dimension on the two variables we just created in a table.

[image]

Add filters where each of those variable is not null...

[image]

And there you have it. You can add any measures you want without having to create detail variables with associated dimensions. However, if you want to add more dimensions from either query you **will** need to create detail variables with the merged City as your associated dimension.

[image]

Noel